# make a div like circly cropped from top right corner

Tags: html, css, crop, css-shapes

how to make a cropped div from top right corner.
like suppose i have a square image and i cut top right corner in circle shape. my question is how to make remaining shape of square image by using pure css???
please help me!!

my code:

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid white;
    border-left: 80px solid red;
    width: 0;
}
```

this code folding top right corner like fold a page. but i need circle cut on top right corner.

Comment: an image of the shape you need would make it much simpler to understand. just a question : do you need it on a plain background?

Comment: you have to put border-top-right-radius: 50%; in both div and image

Comment: web-tiki i need it with transparent background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simlar to @web-tiki answer, but using a box-shadow to paint background , so body background can be seen through. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Kpvuf)**

```
div {
  height: 150px;
  width:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px; right: -40px;
  height: 80px ;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow:red 0 0 0 500px;

}
```

Comment: +1 as OP needs a transparent background, another alternative with border instead of box-shadows : http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/EGcyA

Comment: +1. [This](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/FweLz) is another version of it using `radial-gradient` but ofcourse no support in IE <= 9.

Comment: @Harry , yes, i like this version better and as you mention IE9 behavior, it is unfortunately still to be kept aside :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but here's two interpretations I can come up with based on it:

```css
div {
 height: 300px;
 background: red;
 position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or option two:

```css
div {
 height: 300px;
 background: red;
 position: relative;
}

div:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; right: 0;
 width: 80px; height: 80px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius:80px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```